# How can I create Result class for local test?

Tags: android, mockito, junit4, mockk

I am testing ViewModel. And the method I want to test is RemoteConfigNetworkRepository.

```
class RemoteConfigNetworkRepository(
    private val service: RemoteConfigService
) {
    suspend fun fetchRemoteConfig(isTest: Boolean? = false): Result<RemoteConfig?> {
        return try {
            val response = service.fetchRemoteConfig(isTest)
            if (response.isSuccessful) {
                Result.success(response.body())
            } else {
                throw java.lang.Exception("error")
            }
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            Result.failure(e)
        }
    }
}
```

I want to return fake Result data from this method to test a method in the ViewModel.

How can I test with this method?

```
    @Test
    fun fetchRemoteConfig_saveRemoteConfig() = runTest {
        val fakeRemoteConfig = RemoteConfig(
            0,
            0,
            "",
            0,
        )
        coEvery { remoteRepo.fetchRemoteConfig(true) } returns Result<RemoteConfig>(fakeRemoteConfig) // this return doesn't work.

        viewModel.fetchRemoteConfig(true)
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The constructor of `Result` is internal, you should use `Result.success` instead:

```
coEvery { remoteRepo.fetchRemoteConfig(true) } returns Result.success(fakeRemoteConfig)
```